# SAPUI5- MyRouter.js not working properly

Tags: sapui5

I am following the MVC model of SAPUI5. I have a MyRouter.js which contains the following code:

```
jQuery.sap.declare("sap.ui.demo.Onepage.MyRouter");

sap.ui.demo.Onepage.MyRouter={

    /**
     * to monkey patch the router with the mobile nav back handling
     */
    myNavBack : function (route, data) {
        var history = sap.ui.core.routing.History.getInstance();
        var url = this.getURL(route, data);
        var direction = history.getDirection(url);
        if ("Backwards" === direction) {
            window.history.go(-1);
        } else {
            var replace = true; // otherwise we go backwards with a forward history
            this.navTo(route, data, replace);
        }
    },

    /**
     * to monkey patch the router with a nav to method that
     * does not write hashes but load the views properly
     */
    myNavToWithoutHash : function (viewName, viewType, master, data) {
        var oapp = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Myapp");
        var oview = this.getView(viewName, viewType);
        oapp.addPage(oview, master);
        oapp.to(view.getId(), "show", data);
    }
};
```

Component.js:

```
jQuery.sap.declare("sap.ui.demo.Onepage.Component");

sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("sap.ui.demo.Onepage.Component", {

    metadata : {
        routing : {
            config : {
                viewType : "XML",
                viewPath : "view",
                targetControl : "Myapp",
                targetAggregation: "pages",
                clearTarget : false,
                transition: "slide"
            },
                        routes : [
                {
                    pattern : "",
                    name : "Myapp",
                    view : "App",
                    viewPath : "view",
                    targetAggregation: "pages",
                    viewLevel : 1,

                }]

        }
    },

    /**
     * !!! The steps in here are sequence dependent !!!
     */
    init : function () {

        // 1. some very generic requires
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.routing.RouteMatchedHandler");
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.demo.Onepage.MyRouter");

        // 2. call overridden init (calls createContent)
        sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

        // 3a. monkey patch the router
        var router = this.getRouter();
        router.myNavBack = sap.ui.demo.Onepage.MyRouter.myNavBack;
        router.myNavToWithoutHash = sap.ui.demo.Onepage.MyRouter.myNavToWithoutHash;

        if (!sap.ui.Device.system.phone) {
            router.myNavToWithoutHash("view.hello", "XML", false);
        }

        // 4. initialize the router
        this.routeHandler = new sap.m.routing.RouteMatchedHandler(router);
        router.initialize();
    },

    destroy : function () {
        if (this.routeHandler) {
            this.routeHandler.destroy();
        }

        // call overridden destroy
        sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    createContent : function () {
        // create root view
        var oView = sap.ui.view({
            id : "app",
            viewName : "view.App",
            type : "XML",
            viewData : { component : this }
        });

        // set navigation model
        // load the global data model
        /*var oJSONDataModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/data.json");
        oView.setModel(oJSONDataModel);

        // load the global image source model
        var oImgModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/img.json");
        oView.setModel(oImgModel, "img"); */

        // done
        return oView;
    }
});
```

Everything is working fine until i call the `myNavToWithoutHash` function from any controller. The error i get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addPage' of undefined - MyRouter.js :27
```

I cannot find the possible issue. Please help.

Comment: Which line of the myNavToWithoutHash function?

Comment: I have slightly modified the code. Now the error is on line 27(MyRouter.js). The moment I remove router.myNavToWithoutHash("view.hello", "XML", false); from Component.js(line 47) , the error disappears!

Comment: Could you show me your code of App.view.js?

Comment: App.view.xml :<mvc:View
  height="100%"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns="sap.m">
  <App id="Myapp">
  
  </App>
</mvc:View>

Answer (score 2):

XMLViews do automatic prefixing of IDs. So the real ID of your sap.m.App in the DOM probably is sth. like "__xmlview0--MyApp" whereas "__xmlview0" would be your views id if it has any (just check in Elements Tab). Querying for a control with `sap.ui.getCore().byId()` will not know/respect any of this prefixes. It searches for the id "MyApp" which is obviously != "__xmlview0--MyApp". Since luckily your XMLView has the id "app" you should be fine by doing this:

**`sap.ui.getCore().byId("app--Myapp");`**

So remember: Whenever you use XMLViews you can't use `sap.ui.getCore().byId('MyApp')` but have to use `this.getView().byId('MyApp')` in your views controller.

Furthermore please note that you can use custom router classes by just declaring so in your routing config:

```
metadata : {
        routing : {
            config : {
                routerClass: sap.ui.demo.Onepage.MyRouter,
                viewType : "XML",
                viewPath : "view",
                targetControl : "Myapp",
                targetAggregation: "pages",
                clearTarget : false,
                transition: "slide"
            }
            ...
```

As you might have already guessed your Router therefore needs to extend `sap.ui.core.routing.Router`!

HF
Christian

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to related to not finding the the App.

```
    var oapp = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Myapp");
```

You need to declare **controllerName** attribute for your controller class in  your App.view.xml.

```
<mvc:View height="100%" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="view.App" 
      xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m"> 
    <App id="Myapp" />
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: I don't want the splitapp view. And even if I make these changes , the error is still there. I removed the targetaggregation as i guess its not needed here. Still the error persists.

Comment: Hi, i misunderstood. I just found you didn't delcare controllerName attribute.